# detemining exact 1-form

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show $\frac{dz}{z}$ is an exact $1$-form over $\mathbb{C}- \{0\}$, for that I compute the integral of that? but I'm not sure about that. because in a way we can show that $\frac{dz}{z}$ is not exact (that I'm not sure about that either) that is because of thm: if $\omega$ is exact and $C$ is closed, then $\int_C \omega = 0$, but $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ is not closed, but I think it is isomorphic to a closed one.

Would anybody help me about that?

Comment: $C$ is a closed curve (close mean it forms a cirrle, or $\gamma(0)= \gamma(1)$ more explicitly). It does not mean that the domain is closed.

Comment: Did you compute $\int_C \frac{dz}{z}$ for some curve $C$?

Comment: I define the curve by $\gamma : [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}-{0}$ by $\gamma(\theta)=(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$
I think this curve is closed, but I wasn't sure about my solution.

Comment: So what do you have?

Comment: If this exactness of 1-form doesn't depend on domain, then I can calculate the integral of 1-form under $\gamma$ and show that it's not zero, so $\frac{dz}{z}$ is not exact. is that right?

Comment: Yes, as long as the curve $C$ is inside the domain of $w$, $\int_C w=0$ if $w$ is exact. I guess you got $2\pi i$ for your $C$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, $\dfrac{dz}{z}$ is **not** an exact form in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. Indeed, its integral over the unit circle with counterclockwise orientation is $2\pi i$, not $0$.

The form $\dfrac{dz}{z}$ is exact in every simply-connected domain that does not contain zero, for example $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$. This is because $\log z$ has a single-valued branch in such a domain.